# D3 Zoom - Scales

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3 and trying to use zoom functionality.
I have a 100 thousand plus points to be displayed and inorder to not do break my browser, I am trying to randomly select 5000 points and show the user, and on zooming in - query more relevant points from the database.
I do not want to do this on every zoom , my zoom scaleExtent is set to [1,5] and every time the zoomscale is 3 or 5 I will query data from database and refresh the plot, this works fine, just a problem every time there is a plot refresh the scales are set to [1,5] again and it goes in an endless loop. And zoom out completely breaks.

Anybody have any ideas how to approach doing this.
I tried to create to buttons for zoomin and zoomout and call the function as below onClick them

```
function initiateZoom(val)
{
    var direction = 1
    direction = (val === 'zoom_in') ? 1 : -1;
    extent = zoom.scaleExtent();
    incrZoom = parseInt(lastZoomScale) + parseInt(direction);
    console.log("Target Zoom Scale"+ incrZoom);
    if (incrZoom < extent[0] || incrZoom > extent[1])
    {
        if(incrZoom < extent[0])
        {
            incrZoom = parseInt(incrZoom) + direction;
        }else {
            incrZoom = parseInt(incrZoom) + direction;
        }
        alert("Min/Max Reached");
        return false;
    }
    zoom.scaleTo(scatter_plt_svg, (incrZoom));
}
```

And on zoom call the function zoomed

```
    function zoomed() {
        var zoom_scale = (d3.event.transform.k);//.toFixed(2);
        var new_xScale= null;
        var new_yScale = null;
        new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScl);
        new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScl);
        // update axes
        gX.call(d3.axisBottom(new_xScale).ticks(10));
        gY.call(d3.axisLeft(new_yScale).ticks(10));
        circles.data(plotdata)
            .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
                return new_xScale(d[1])
            })
            .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
                return new_yScale(d[2])
            });

        curr_xScale = new_xScale;
        curr_yScale = new_yScale;
        lastZoomScale = zoom_scale;
        //If zoom scale is a value of scaleExtent, refresh plot.
        if(zoom_scale == 2 || zoom_scale == 4 || zoom_scale == 6 || zoom_scale == 8 || zoom_scale == 10)
        {
            scatter_plt_svg.on('.zoom', null);
            initialize_plots(false,"zoom"); //helps get data from server and refresh plots.
        }
    }
```

Regards
Tasneem

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: updated my question with some code snippets now.